# VBA: Testing for perfect cubes

Tags: vba, excel, user-defined-functions

I'm trying to write a simple function in VBA that will test a real value and output a string result if it's a perfect cube.  Here's my code:

```
Function PerfectCubeTest(x as Double)

    If (x) ^ (1 / 3) = Int(x) Then
        PerfectCubeTest = "Perfect"
    Else
        PerfectCubeTest = "Flawed"
    End If

End Function
```

As you can see, I'm using a simple if statement to test if the cube root of a value is equal to its integer portion (i.e. no remainder).  I tried testing the function with some perfect cubes (1, 8, 27, 64, 125), but it only works for the number 1.  Any other value spits out the "Flawed" case.  Any idea what's wrong here?

Answer (score 6):

You are testing whether the cube is equal to the double supplied.

So for 8 you would be testing whether 2 = 8.

EDIT:  Also found a floating point issue.  To resolve we will round the decimals a little to try and overcome the issue.

Change to the following:

```
Function PerfectCubeTest(x As Double)

    If Round((x) ^ (1 / 3), 10) = Round((x) ^ (1 / 3), 0) Then
        PerfectCubeTest = "Perfect"
    Else
        PerfectCubeTest = "Flawed"
    End If

End Function
```

Or (Thanks to Ron)

```
Function PerfectCubeTest(x As Double)

    If CDec(x ^ (1 / 3)) = Int(CDec(x ^ (1 / 3))) Then
        PerfectCubeTest = "Perfect"
    Else
        PerfectCubeTest = "Flawed"
    End If


End Function
```

[image]

Comment: ... wow, I'm an idiot.  Thank you so much, that was exactly my issue.

Comment: Fails for **64**

Comment: @Gary'sStudent interesting, must be a floating decimal issue.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent fixed it.

Comment: @heygivethatback look at the edit,  There is a floating point issue with the old method.  I have fixed it.

Comment: @ScottCraner  Also `CDec(x ^ (1 / 3)) = Int(CDec(x ^ (1 / 3)))`

Comment: @ScottCraner Unfortunately, it seems to fail with values of `728,757,026,999` or greater (`8999^3`).  So I guess you'll still need to use Rounding.

Comment: Somehow all versions including my 1st version give me `Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument` with negative variable, but are fine with negative constant

Comment: @Slai then just test the Abs of the input instead.

Answer (score 3):

@ScottCraner correctly explains why you were getting incorrect results, but there are a couple other things to point out here.  First, I'm assuming that you are taking a `Double` as input because the range of acceptable numbers is higher.  However, by your implied definition of a perfect cube only numbers with an integer cube root (i.e. it would exclude 3.375) need to be evaluated. I'd just test for this up front to allow an early exit.

The next issue you run into is that 1 / 3 can't be represented exactly by a `Double`.  Since you're raising to the inverse power to get your cube root you're also compounding the floating point error.  There's a *really* easy way to avoid this - take the cube root, cube it, and see if it matches the input.  You get around the rest of the floating point errors by going back to your definition of a perfect cube as an integer value - just round the cube root to *both* the next higher and next lower integer before you re-cube it:

```
Public Function IsPerfectCube(test As Double) As Boolean
    'By your definition, no non-integer can be a perfect cube.
    Dim rounded As Double
    rounded = Fix(test)
    If rounded <> test Then Exit Function

    Dim cubeRoot As Double
    cubeRoot = rounded ^ (1 / 3)
    'Round both ways, then test the cube for equity.
    If Fix(cubeRoot) ^ 3 = rounded Then
        IsPerfectCube = True
    ElseIf (Fix(cubeRoot) + 1) ^ 3 = rounded Then
        IsPerfectCube = True
    End If
End Function
```

This returned the correct result up to 1E+27 (1 billion cubed) when I tested it. I stopped going higher at that point because the test was taking so long to run and by that point you're probably outside of the range that you would reasonably need it to be accurate.

Comment: never mind .. the limit seems to be at `208064 ^ 3 - 1`

Comment: @Slai - That makes sense - that's roughly the *integer* precision of a `Double`.

Comment: So the only reason I used `Double` as the input is because my instructor for this VBA class recommended using either `Single` or `Double` variable types when dealing with variables that can be changed by the spreadsheet user.  Thank you for the informative and somewhat over-my-head code (what exactly is `Fix()` doing here?).  Also, what's floating point error?

Comment: @heygivethatback - [`Fix()`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Int-Fix-Functions-5446da0c-fbdc-425f-a818-7e3153984ff8) basically does the same thing as `Int()`, but has slightly different behavior with negative numbers. The floating point error refers to [how non-integers are stored internally](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format). What it comes down to is that [irrational numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrational_number) can't be accurately represented in binary.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed the integer division error thanks to @Comintern. Seems to be correct up to `208064 ^ 3 - 2`

```
Function isPerfectCube(n As Double) As Boolean 
    n = Abs(n)
    isPerfectCube = n = Int(n ^ (1 / 3) - (n > 27)) ^ 3
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

For fun, here is an implementation of a number-theory based method described [here](http://burningmath.blogspot.com/2013/09/how-to-know-or-check-if-number-is.html) . It defines a Boolean-valued (rather than string-valued) function called `PerfectCube()` that tests if an integer input (represented as a Long) is a perfect cube. It first runs a quick test which throws away many numbers. If the quick test fails to classify it, it invokes a factoring-based method. Factor the number and check if the multiplicity of each prime factor is a multiple of 3. I could probably optimize this stage by not bothering to find the complete factorization when a bad factor is found, but I had a VBA factoring algorithm already lying around:

```
Function DigitalRoot(n As Long) As Long
    'assumes that n >= 0
    Dim sum As Long, digits As String, i As Long

    If n < 10 Then
        DigitalRoot = n
        Exit Function
    Else
        digits = Trim(Str(n))
        For i = 1 To Len(digits)
            sum = sum + Mid(digits, i, 1)
        Next i
        DigitalRoot = DigitalRoot(sum)
    End If
End Function

Sub HelperFactor(ByVal n As Long, ByVal p As Long, factors As Collection)
    'Takes a passed collection and adds to it an array of the form
    '(q,k) where q >= p is the smallest prime divisor of n
    'p is assumed to be odd
    'The function is called in such a way that
    'the first divisor found is automatically prime

    Dim q As Long, k As Long
    q = p
    Do While q <= Sqr(n)
        If n Mod q = 0 Then
            k = 1
            Do While n Mod q ^ k = 0
                k = k + 1
            Loop
            k = k - 1 'went 1 step too far
            factors.Add Array(q, k)
            n = n / q ^ k
            If n > 1 Then HelperFactor n, q + 2, factors
            Exit Sub
        End If
        q = q + 2
    Loop
    'if we get here then n is prime - add it as a factor
    factors.Add Array(n, 1)
End Sub

Function factor(ByVal n As Long) As Collection
    Dim factors As New Collection
    Dim k As Long

    Do While n Mod 2 ^ k = 0
        k = k + 1
    Loop
    k = k - 1
    If k > 0 Then
        n = n / 2 ^ k
        factors.Add Array(2, k)
    End If
    If n > 1 Then HelperFactor n, 3, factors
    Set factor = factors
End Function

Function PerfectCubeByFactors(n As Long) As Boolean
    Dim factors As Collection
    Dim f As Variant

    Set factors = factor(n)
    For Each f In factors
        If f(1) Mod 3 > 0 Then
            PerfectCubeByFactors = False
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next f
    'if we get here:
    PerfectCubeByFactors = True
End Function

Function PerfectCube(n As Long) As Boolean
    Dim d As Long
    d = DigitalRoot(n)
    If d = 0 Or d = 1 Or d = 8 Or d = 9 Then
        PerfectCube = PerfectCubeByFactors(n)
    Else
        PerfectCube = False
    End If
End Function
```